# VBA to trace precedents of index function

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

Thanks in advance.

Has anyone created a `VBA` sub that traces the precedent of an `INDEX`?

For example, suppose A1 has:
`INDEX(namedRange, namedCellVertical, namedCellHorizontal)`

I would like to be able to select `A1`, run a macro, and then have the activated cell be the particular cell (not the entire range) that `A1` refers to.

It seems that there is freeware *(Arixcel)* that does this (and a lot more), but we can't install it on our computers at work because of our policies.

Again, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Sub GetCell()
Dim c As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set c = Selection.Parent.Evaluate(Selection.Formula)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        If c.Parent.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then c.Parent.Activate
        c.Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `INDEX()` just happens to return a range - makes sense if you think about the purpose of that function. On a worksheet it shows the value of the cell, and in VBA `? Activesheet.Evaluate(Selection.Formula)` will also default to showing the cell's value.  However, `? TypeName(Activesheet.Evaluate(Selection.Formula))` gives "Range".  Note: same is also true for a simple formula like `=A1`

Comment: THANK YOU!......I never realized that INDEX() returns a range......I'll have to study this a little.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Excellent answer, exactly what I was looking for, and ditto +1 elegant code.